# Почему класс ECDsaCng постоянно генерирует одинаковый ключ?

Tags: c#, .net

По примеру, ключ извлекается в массив байтов key. Но экземпляр класса ECDsaCng постоянно генерирует одинаковый ключ. Это правильно? Даже на мсдн сказано, что ECDsaCng -"Инициализирует новый экземпляр класса ECDsaCng парой случайных ключей". Как сделать, чтобы при каждом создание экземпляра ECDsaCng генерировался новый ключ?

```
class Alice
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bob bob = new Bob();
            using (ECDsaCng dsa = new ECDsaCng())
            {
                dsa.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256;
                bob.key = dsa.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);

                byte[] data = new byte[] { 21, 5, 8, 12, 207 };

                byte[] signature = dsa.SignData(data);

                bob.Receive(data, signature);
            }
        }

    }

    public class Bob
    {
        public byte[] key;

        public void Receive(byte[] data, byte[] signature)
        {
            using (ECDsaCng ecsdKey = new ECDsaCng(CngKey.Import(key, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob)))
            {
                if (ecsdKey.VerifyData(data, signature))
                    Console.WriteLine("Data is good");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Data is bad");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: код падает с эксепшеном из-за неправильно выбранного `HashAlgorithm`. при замене `HashAlgorithm` на другой - генерирует каждый раз новый ключ (похожий на предыдущий в начале ключа, но другой)